# Splitting columns into rows from a text file using unix shell script - Dynamically changing source file structure

Tags: shell, csv, unix, sh

**I've a tab seperated source file with this structure:** Only the first 9 columns from ID to Line Item/Property is fixed, rest are all dynamic varying in count and structure.

```
ID  Date/Time (UTC) User    Description Security Change Previous Value  New Value   Module/List Line Item/Property  Scenarios   Region EM2  Plan Item PB6   Market EM4  Plants - Master Plan Brand PB4  T/DI    GRS 6   GRS 7   Target User Import  Object  Target Role Export  Dashboard   Action  Time
```

**Here's one sample record from that file**

```
2572561 3/24/2020 14:01 chiara.bettini@gmail.com            FALSE   TRUE    FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market  Plan Brands                     Polly Pocket                chiara.bettini@gmail.com
```

I need to change it to the below struture as **a CSV file with the following headers and data format** using Unix shell script. I want to keep the permanent columns (ID till Line Item/Property) as such and park all other dynamically variable columns into Attribute Name & Attribute Value column:

```
ID,Date/Time (UTC),User,Description,Security Change,Previous Value,New Value,Module/List,Line Item/Property,Attribute Name,Attribute Value
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Scenarios,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Region EM2,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plan Item PB6,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Market EM4,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plants - Master,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plan Brand PB4,Polly Pocket
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,T/DI,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,GRS 6,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,GRS 7,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Target User,chiara.bettini@gmail.com
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Import,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Object,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Target Role,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Export,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Dashboard,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Action,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Time,
```

Comment: Kindly wrap your samples in code tags in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Please remove the email address and replace it by some dummy vallue like foo@bar.

Comment: It's already a dummy email address

Comment: Please clarify how to handle commas (`,`) in original data records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: the following will **not** work correctly if any field contains a comma character (`,`).*

Try this `bash` script (named `process` for the terminal session that follows):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

tr '\t' ',' | {
    IFS=',' # separator for all array reads and printfs

    # read and output heading
    read -r -a heading
    printf "%s\n" "${heading[*]:0:9},Attribute Name,Attribute Value"    

    # process one line of data
    while read -r -a data ; do
        for (( i=9; i<${#heading[*]}; ++i )) ; do
            printf "%s\n" "${data[*]:0:9},${heading[i]},${data[i]}"
        done
    done
}
```

Terminal session:

```sh
$ cat data.in | tr '\t' ','
ID,Date/Time (UTC),User,Description,Security Change,Previous Value,New Value,Module/List,Line Item/Property,Scenarios,Region EM2,Plan Item PB6,Market EM4,Plants - Master,Plan Brand PB4,T/DI,GRS 6,GRS 7,Target User,Import,Object,Target Role,Export,Dashboard,Action,Time
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,,,,,,Polly Pocket,,,,chiara.bettini@gmail.com
$ ./process < data.in 
ID,Date/Time (UTC),User,Description,Security Change,Previous Value,New Value,Module/List,Line Item/Property,Attribute Name,Attribute Value
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Scenarios,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Region EM2,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plan Item PB6,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Market EM4,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plants - Master,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Plan Brand PB4,Polly Pocket
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,T/DI,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,GRS 6,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,GRS 7,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Target User,chiara.bettini@gmail.com
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Import,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Object,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Target Role,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Export,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Dashboard,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Action,
2572561,3/24/2020 14:01,chiara.bettini@gmail.com,,,FALSE,TRUE,FILTER:  Brand P&L Report - Market,Plan Brands,Time,
$
```

Comment: I have to convert columns to rows. That's a major challenge here. That too from a dynamically changing source structure

Comment: You input and sample output do not show any row-column transpose operation...  Nevermind I understand it now...

Comment: Yeah, sorry, changed the question to add that

Comment: Do you have a choice of language?  I don't recommend `bash`.  I could show you a solution in `tcl`.

Comment: No, Unix shell script.